# How to start passenger production when ubuntu or server starts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, ubuntu-14.04

I developed a Ruby On Rails application and want to deploy in production (intranet).
As of now i created an sh file to run the passenger like so:

```
cd /pathofmyapp
passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -d -e production
cd /pathofmyapp2
passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -d -e production
```

When the ubuntu server starts i have to execute the sh or manually start the passenger.
Is their a way to automate this so that whenever the ubuntu server starts, the command will automatically run or the ruby on rails application will start?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [UbuntuBootupHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto) will completely answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add that to your cronjob to run the code on reboot.

```
@reboot     cd /pathofmyapp && passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -d -e production
```